# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova exclude folder from build

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

I have a Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015. 
I've added some node modules, which doesn't display in project (in VS), but exists on disk, when all other files in project folder were added there by default without excluding. 
So now I need a way to exclude `node_modules` from build, 'cause there're just dev tools (autoprefixer, less, watch, etc.), in case of that generated apk file size increases, which's not applicable for me (total size ~10MB, without node_modules - only 3MB). Does it really possible to do that without physical removing that folder? Maybe I don't know about some configurations or so on?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such configurations in visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution I found was to move `node_modules` to parent directory and fix paths in config files.